# IE10 pseudo elements on an <hr> with negative positioning not working

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to negatively position `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements on a `<hr>`, but IE10 is being stubborn and just not showing those elements.

Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/Shpigford/HyVMR/

That seems to work fine in all browsers except for IE10. It doesn't show the left and right blocks.

It works fine with a `<div>`, but using a `<hr>` causes the left pseudo elements to not show up at all

CSS:

```
hr {
    background:red;
    margin:0 150px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
}
hr:before {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    left:-150px;
    width:150px;
    background:green;
}
hr:after {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    right:-150px;
    width:150px;
    background:blue;
}
```

​

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to do this - I dare say IE10 is being standards-compliant here, and all other browsers are violating the spec.

Comment: What does the spec specifically say about this?

Comment: Having `:before` and `:after` on empty elements is a topic of hot debate, but the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) seems to forbid it... `hr` as a void element can't have document tree content, so it would seem incorrect for a browser to insert generated content anyway. It's been known that you *can* insert `:before` and `:after` content even for things like form elements, and only in certain browsers but not others.

Comment: Gotcha. If you want to make one of these your answer, feel free too. Seems sufficient to me.

Comment: After a few more tests, it looks like IE does this consistently (IE8+). I should add that there's an informative note that says CSS2.1 doesn't define how these should work with replaced elements. That may or may not include form elements and `hr`.

Comment: I don't know what html version you use, but in case of xhtml/html5 you should change `<hr>` into `<hr/>`. I don't know if this is the source of the problem though.

Comment: @BoltClock maybe, as I said I don't know if this has anything to do with it. But it's a good tip nonetheless :)

Answer (score 15):

Try **overflow:visible;** on `<hr>`

```
hr {
background:red;
margin:0 150px;
height:50px;
position:relative;
overflow:visible;
```

}

Comment: Thanks. This helps resolved my question on the matter as well. Short and sweet.